# Screenshots often come out corrupted

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, screenshots

I have a first generation Moto G (XT1033) with Android 5.0.

Often when taking screenshots, it gets stuck at the *Screenshot is being saved* message - then I have to forcefully close the *System UI* process if I want it to go away.

And the final file is corrupted (either the PNG file will not open on a PC or, for image viewers that are more tolerant to broken files, it will be black except for a small portion of the image). For an example:

[image]

See that the image is correct up to a point. It seems as if the file was closed before the system finished writing to it.

What can be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I gave up and did a reset of the phone. The problem didn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another temporary fix other than rebooting is doing another screenshot. The next screenshot would override the stuck one.

PS: It might take 2-3 attempts to fix it.